# Number of combinations where A and B are together

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

This question has been answered before, but I want an elaboration as to why:

If there are 10 people including A and B, how many arrangements in a line(I guess this is permutation since order does matter), how many of these arrangements are A and B together?

The answer is $2!9!$, but why? I don't understand the intuition because intuitively, it seems like it should be $2!8!$:

This is a word formation problem, we need two letters (A and B) to be side by side, the possible number of ways to arrange two letters side by side is $2!$, leaving use 8 other letters to choose from to create the remaining 8 spaces which is $8!$, so $2!8!$

My book says that we treat the pair as a single object, so there are $2!$ to arrange this object, and then $(n - 1)! = 9!$ to arrange the remaining people. But doesn't this include combinations where A and B are **not** together since $9!$ considers possibilities of where A is not seated next to B?

Why is my reasoning incorrect and why is the book reasoning correct (or why is $2!8!$ wrong and $2!9!$ correct)?

Comment: As $A$,$B$ must be together you can treat them as a block.  There are exactly $9!$ permutations using the block $AB$, and $9!$ using the block $BA$.  The $9!$ does not consider possibilities where $A$ and $B$ are non-adjacent.

Comment: No, there are not $(n-1)!$ ways to arrange the remaining people - there are $(n-1)!$ ways to arrange the "objects", where one object is the pair, and the rest are the $n-2$ remaining people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another point of view: we have to place $8$ persons, some of them on the left of the pair $AB$, the rest on the right.

Let's say $k$ persons are on the left. We have  $\dbinom 8k$ ways to choose them, and have $k!$ permutations of these persons. Similarly, there are $(8-k)!$ permutations of the persons on the right, so finally there are $\;2!\dbinom8k k!\,(8-k)!=2!\,8!$ arrangements with $k$ persons on the left.

This makes in all:
$$\sum_{k=0}^82!\,8!=9\cdot2!\,8!=2!\,9!$$

Answer (score 1):

Intuition is very simple here, we look at A and B like it is one person, then we have to arrange 9 person, it is $9!$. One AB and $8$ others.

And we can say first A than B, or first B than A, so:

$$2!9!$$

Answer (score -1):

This is because 9 times 8! Is 9!

Comment: Would the downvoter elaborate? There are 9 positions for 8 people, hence 8! permutations in each optoon: 9 times 8! is 9!

Comment: I imagine that the downvote was cast since the factor of $9$ is attributable to the fact that we are permuting nine objects, the unit consisting of two people, and the eight other people.

Comment: but that's exactly what I pointed out: there are 8 people, hence $8!$ permutations for each positions, and there are 9 position. So I don't understand...

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your argument.  Are you saying that there are $8!$ ways of arranging the other eight people in a row and nine ways of fitting the block of two people in the nine gaps (including the seven spaces between successive people and the two ends of the row)?

Comment: 9 positions for the block of 2 people;8! for the remaining each for each of these positions

Comment: If you edit your answer to include that information, I would certainly cast an upvote.

Comment: Why should I do it? IMO I gave enough hint for the OP to be able to solve the problem

Comment: Look at all the clarification you had to do in comments. Is there a reason you are not doing that in the answer? (I am the downvoter, and did so because the answer is  useless. If you added your clarifications from comments to the answer, it would be an okay answer.)

Comment: Read my previous comment. I find it quite useful.